# Code resign using Ipa not failing with Installaation error-IOS

Tags: ios, iphone

I am doing it through command line .The code is from third party developer.Previously it is working.Now it says Installation failed.

I use following code to resign

1. Unzip the .ipa file
   unzip app.ipa
2. Delete the current code signature file
   rm -rf Payload/MyApp.app/_CodeSignature/
3. Add in the new provisioning profile
   cp ~/Downloads/AdHoc.mobileprovision Payload/MyApp.app/embedded.mobileprovision
4. resign the code
   codesign -f -s "iPhone Distribution: Company Certificate" --resource-rules Payload/MyApp.app/ResourceRules.plist Payload/MyApp.app
5. rearchive the app into an .ipa file 
   zip -qr app-resigned.ipa  Payload/

Answer (score 0):

You also need to resign Framework, Dylibs, Appex,... files too.
But for best way to find problem of install, open XCode->Device and select your iphone to view log message when install failed.